# Remove weekend gaps in amcharts for candlestick chart

Tags: javascript, amcharts

I am constructed candlestick chart similar to the one in the link below
https://www.amcharts.com/demos/stock-comparing-external-data/

After clicking on the 10D zoom button you can see that there is not a gap between candles over weekend. My chart unfortunately has empty space during the weekend. Are there any settings in Amcharts to remove gaps when data is not present?

Thanks for help

Answer (score 2):

You will need to set [categoryAxesSettings.equalSpacing](https://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptstockchart/CategoryAxesSettings#equalSpacing) to `true`.

Answer (score 0):

Set `skipEmptyPeriods` setting to `true`.
It will remove weekend gap.

Example:

```
dateAxis.skipEmptyPeriods = true;
```

amChart docs:
https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/concepts/axes/date-axis/#Removing_empty_time_units